# PANDAS Create Dataframe from list of items that need parsing and matching

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of item and country status.

```
res = [('63(I)[PARA.8]','AFGHANISTAN Y ARGENTINA Y AUSTRALIA Y BELGIUM Y BOLIVIA Y BRAZIL N BYELORUSSIAN SSR Y CANADA Y CHILE Y CHINA A COLOMBIA Y COSTA RICA Y CUBA A CZECHOSLOVAKIA Y DENMARK Y DOMINICAN REPUBLIC A ECUADOR Y EGYPT Y EL SALVADOR Y ETHIOPIA Y FRANCE Y GREECE Y GUATEMALA  HAITI Y HONDURAS Y ICELAND A INDIA Y IRAN Y IRAQ Y LEBANON N LIBERIA Y LUXEMBOURG Y MEXICO Y NETHERLANDS Y NEW ZEALAND Y NICARAGUA Y NORWAY Y PANAMA Y PARAGUAY Y PERU Y PHILIPPINE REPUBLIC N POLAND Y SAUDI ARABIA Y SWEDEN Y SYRIA Y TURKEY N UKRAINIAN SSR Y UNION OF SOUTH AFRICA N USSR Y UNITED KINGDOM Y UNITED STATES Y URUGUAY A VENEZUELA N YUGOSLAVIA'),
 ('63(I)[PARA.7]',
  'AFGHANISTAN Y ARGENTINA Y AUSTRALIA Y BELGIUM Y BOLIVIA Y BRAZIL N BYELORUSSIAN SSR Y CANADA Y CHILE Y CHINA A COLOMBIA Y COSTA RICA Y CUBA A CZECHOSLOVAKIA Y DENMARK Y DOMINICAN REPUBLIC A ECUADOR Y EGYPT Y EL SALVADOR Y ETHIOPIA Y FRANCE Y GREECE Y GUATEMALA  HAITI Y HONDURAS Y ICELAND A INDIA Y IRAN Y IRAQ Y LEBANON N LIBERIA Y LUXEMBOURG Y MEXICO Y NETHERLANDS Y NEW ZEALAND Y NICARAGUA Y NORWAY Y PANAMA Y PARAGUAY Y PERU Y PHILIPPINE REPUBLIC N POLAND Y SAUDI ARABIA Y SWEDEN Y SYRIA Y TURKEY N UKRAINIAN SSR Y UNION OF SOUTH AFRICA N USSR Y UNITED KINGDOM Y UNITED STATES Y URUGUAY A VENEZUELA N YUGOSLAVIA'),
 ('63(I)[PARA.6]',
  'AFGHANISTAN Y ARGENTINA Y AUSTRALIA Y BELGIUM Y BOLIVIA Y BRAZIL N BYELORUSSIAN SSR Y CANADA Y CHILE Y CHINA A COLOMBIA Y COSTA RICA Y CUBA A CZECHOSLOVAKIA Y DENMARK Y DOMINICAN REPUBLIC A ECUADOR Y EGYPT Y EL SALVADOR Y ETHIOPIA Y FRANCE Y GREECE Y GUATEMALA  HAITI Y HONDURAS Y ICELAND A INDIA Y IRAN Y IRAQ Y LEBANON N LIBERIA Y LUXEMBOURG Y MEXICO Y NETHERLANDS Y NEW ZEALAND Y NICARAGUA Y NORWAY Y PANAMA Y PARAGUAY Y PERU Y PHILIPPINE REPUBLIC N POLAND Y SAUDI ARABIA Y SWEDEN Y SYRIA Y TURKEY N UKRAINIAN SSR Y UNION OF SOUTH AFRICA N USSR Y UNITED KINGDOM Y UNITED STATES Y URUGUAY A VENEZUELA N YUGOSLAVIA'),
 ('99(I)', 'No Data'),
 ('50(I)', 'No Data')]
```

How can I create a Dataframe with these columns

```
columns = ['Country','63(I)[PARA.8]','63(I)[PARA.7]','63(I)[PARA.6]','99(I)','50(I)']
dfte = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
dfte
```

With countries mapped in Country column, the "Y", "N", "A" or nan will fill into the cells. "No Data" means column 99(I) & 50(I) will be blank.

```
Country      63(I)[PARA.8]  63(I)[PARA.7]   63(I)[PARA.6]   99(I)   50(I)
AFGHANISTAN      Y               Y               Y
ARGENTINA        Y               Y               Y
AUSTRALIA        Y               Y               Y
...
```

Comment: you should reorganize your `res` to be a dict then pass that in as the data. `df = pd.DataFrame(data=res_new, columns=columns)`

Comment: @noah yeah I'm having trouble putting it to a dict and parse the country status....

Comment: Depending on how complex your data is/how much more there is than what you are showing it might be easiest just to use find/replace in any text editor to put commas where whitespace is etc

Comment: What is the rule for Guatamela?  The data has '... GREECE Y GUATEMALA  HAITI Y...' (Guatemala has no single-letter code; every other country has 'Y', 'N' or 'A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard part is to parse the list of countries and codes (A, N or Y).

- Some countries have embedded spaces (e.g., El Salvador).
- Guatemala has no code (so I used '?')

First, write a function to convert each tuple to a pandas Series.  The 'code' is A, N or Y.  Anything else is (part of) the country name.

```
def raw_data_to_series(xs):
    
    name, values = xs
    
    if values == 'No Data':
        return pd.Series(dtype='object').rename(name)

    values = values.replace('  ', ' ').split(' ')

    country = ''
    results = dict()
    
    for x in values:
        if x == 'GUATEMALA':
            results[x] = '?'
            country = ''
        elif country == '':
            country = x
        elif x in {'A', 'N', 'Y'}:
            results[country] = x
            country = ''
        else:
            country = country + ' ' + x
    
    return pd.Series(results).rename(name)
```

Now, we just pass each element of `res` to the function (using a list comprehension):

```
pd.concat( [raw_data_to_series(r) for r in res], axis=1)


# first 10 lines
                 63(I)[PARA.8] 63(I)[PARA.7] 63(I)[PARA.6] 99(I) 50(I)
AFGHANISTAN                  Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
ARGENTINA                    Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
AUSTRALIA                    Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
BELGIUM                      Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
BOLIVIA                      Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
BRAZIL                       N             N             N   NaN   NaN
BYELORUSSIAN SSR             Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
CANADA                       Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
CHILE                        Y             Y             Y   NaN   NaN
CHINA                        A             A             A   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! there're some country with no value behind like "GUATEMALA". I replace the "  " with some other value.